# Storing and updating checkbox array with PHP sessions

Tags: php, session, checkbox

I have a signup form with a list of sports in checkbox form (pulled from a mysql table). On post, I create a session with variables pertaining to the form that can be validated. Everything works as planned except storing the checkboxes of the sports. I am already passing my post values through an array so it's like passing an array through an array and that's where I'm not having any luck. I just want the checked sports from post to show. Additionally, if that list is updated on a 2nd or 3rd validation I want that to update the array. Code is as follow, thanks in advance.

Post code

```
if(isset($_POST['signup']) == 'Finish') { 

//start session to store variables for post-submit validation
session_start();

//sanitizes input and prevents sql injection attacks
foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
    $data[$key] = filter($value);
    $_SESSION[$key] = $value;
}

$_SESSION['sport'] = array_unique(array_values(array_merge($_SESSION['sport'], $data['sport'])));
```

Form code

```
        <table class="signup_sportstable" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="4">';

        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM sports ORDER BY sport ASC");

        $i = 0;
        $max_columns = 3;
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            foreach ($_SESSION['sport'] as $sport_id) {
                $checked = 'checked';
            }

            // make the variables easy to deal with
            extract($row);

            // open row if counter is zero
            if($i == 0)
            $content .= '<tr>';

            // make sure we have a valid product
            if($sport != "" && $sport != null)
            $content .= '<td><input type="checkbox" name="sport[]" value="'.$sport_id.'" id="sport[]" '.$checked.'>'.$sport.'</td>';

            // increment counter - if counter = max columns, reset counter and close row
            if(++$i == $max_columns) {
             $content .= '</tr>';
             $i=0;
            }  // end if 
        } // end while

        // clean up table
        if($i > 0) {
                for($j=$i; $j<$max_columns;$j++) $content .= "<td>&nbsp;</td>";
            $content .= '</tr>';
        }

    $content .= '
    </table>
```

**Update!!!**

I forgot to mention initially that my code checks every box once the session is created, rather than just checking the boxes that were initially checked. I was informed this was because my checked condition based on my code was always true,so...

Replaced:

```
foreach ($_SESSION['sport'] as $sport_id) {
            $checked = 'checked';
        }
```

With:

```
if (in_array($sport_id, $_SESSION['sport'])) {
    $checked = 'checked';
} else {
    $checked = '';
```

Now, it remembers two checkboxes but after every submit it checks the one immediately to the right of the one i checked the first time. If I hit submit again, its another spot to the right.
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the following seems odd to me:

```
//sanitizes input and prevents sql injection attacks
foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
    $data[$key] = filter($value);
    $_SESSION[$key] = $value;
}
```

Does this mean that you're saving everything in `$_POST` to your `$_SESSION`? That can't be what you want, since if you're using your session in another part of your site for login information, and for instance store the username in `$_SESSION['username']`, then someone can override this with submitting your form with a 'username' parameter. So you probably don't want to do that; I'd suggest just checking for the POST variables you actually want and sanitize them to where you want them.

I'd suggest changing your code to something like:

```
$sports = array();
if (isset($_POST['sport']) && is_array($_POST['sport'])) {
    foreach ($_POST['sport'] as $sport) {
        if (is_numeric($sport)) // example sanitation, since only numeric ids are allowed
            $sports[] = $sport;
    }
    $_SESSION['sports'] = $sports;
} elseif (isset($_SESSION['sports'])) {
    $sports = $_SESSION['sports'];
}
```

This will allow the user to override the sports in the session if they submit any sports. If you want to allow an empty sports array in the session, you'd want to change the check in the first if-statement to something like `if (isset($_POST['submit'])`, to check if the form was submitted (and your submit button is named 'submit').

If the first condition fails (i.e., there's no new sports array passed), the sports array that was stored in the session will be used.

Then, your second part of the code to check if a sport was checked, would be something like:

```
$checked = in_array($id, $sports);
$content .= '<td><input type="checkbox" name="sport[]" value="'.$id.'" id="sport'.$id.'" '.($checked?'checked="checked':'').'>'.$name.'</td>';
```

(Assuming that `$id` and `$name` are set properly.)

**Update:** Also check whether the sport array from `POST` is actually an array.

Comment: Thanks for your concern about the session, but that page will only be accessible by non authenticated users and the session is destroyed when mysql is actually submitted error free.

Comment: Why don't you just use a local variable for this? I don't see the point of using your session for something like this. What if you are using an external library or plan to extend your software in the future? (And still, you can just name the properties you want, there's nothing wrong with that.)

Comment: Depending on where you submit, why can't you just refer to `$_POST` then? Otherwise, I'd suggest using something like `$_SESSION['sports_post_data']`. That's a lot cleaner.